# Civ 6 Rise and Fall Cede Cities and Free Cities

Tags: civilization-6, civilization-6-rise-and-fall

How does occupied and cedeing cities work now that you have loyalty forcing your cities to turn into a free city? I can think of countless scenarios where occupied cities seem to be removed from the game entirely?

Comment: Are you sure anything changed? I never heard about anything changing to how occupying and ceding worked

Comment: @n_palum it has definitely changed because if a city becomes a free city and then you attack it or if the city converts via loyalty there is no occupying status or ceding. So for example what if you have an occupied city (can you even have an occupied city anymore?) what happens if the occupied city becomes a free city and you retake it?

Comment: Occupation isn't a permanent status though as long as you get it from ceding

Comment: @n_palum what I am saying is, you can't even "cede" a city anymore all an enemy has to do is lower your loyalty enough. There is so many scenarios where cedeing is removed from the game I don't understand how it works anymore. Can you purposely lower the loyalty of a occupied city to make it a free city and avoid needing to cede it anymore?

Comment: If it's still an occupied city, you're still at war, no?  So can it even convert to a free city at that stage? I'm asking if your speculation is even possible

Comment: @n_palum you mean occupied cities do not last forever anymore? I thought you still had occupied cities after the war was over.

Comment: I never thought they did but maybe I'm misremembering

Comment: @n_palum apparently you are right, but I don't know when they updated this because originally occupation lasted forever until ceding... what is the point of having ceding in the trade screen now??

Comment: I've played a single game so far, and in it I took and kept two cities in a war. Both revolted after 3 turns of occupation so I razed all the cities after that. I won before declaring peace so I cannot say if I would have been given the option to retain those free cities.

Answer (score 0):

It appears occupation has been completely removed when you end a war with a player. This is not how it originally was I am not sure if the most recent update removed this. A city turning into a free city will prevent any occupation status and even remove occupation status if still at war with the other player.